# Ajax not giving results under wampserver

Tags: ajax, localhost, wampserver

I've been trying to figure out why the content in my very simple ajax file isn't working for the past hour or so.
I'm using wamp server, so I deployed my file under the www folder and ran it from the localhost, no results. I also tried to run it as an independent html file, no results as well.

I'm using Google chrome. I ran an example code from the web (it was embedded in the webpage), it worked perfectly, but after copy-pasting it, didn't work. Why?
Are there any settings I should make sure of in either my browser or server?

Please help! I can't seem to find the problem

here's the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: @mithunsatheesh there you go

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no issues.

just add a div with id `myDiv` inisde the body tag

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

then make sure the ajax target page exists. (ajax_info.txt)

then invoke the `loadXMLDoc` function onload of the page

```
<body onload="loadXMLDoc()">
```

the resultant code might look like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadXMLDoc()">
<div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

if still `myDiv` doesnt get the ajax response, check the `firebug/chrome inspector console` for any errors.

Comment: @user1929226 : if you copy the full html i dumped above into an html page and put another file named `ajax_info.txt` with some test in the same folder as the html file and invoke it via a server(not directly double clicking on it!) by hosting on the wamp and accessing the localhost url, you would surely see the file contents in the div. Else post the firebug error you are seeing on the console.